# How to ensure that value in a report is greater than 0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a counter on employees such that when when a complaint is made about them this counter decreases by 1.

Every employee starts with 10 tokens.

I made a process on the complaint page such that when a complaint is created, the token count decreases by 1.

I have a table in my database which has the `employee_id` and their `token count`.

This table is displayed in an interactive report on apex.

The problem is that even when an employee has a token count of 0, employers can still create complaints about them.

**I want** an error to show up in the complaints creation form that blocks them from making a complaint until that employee has more than 0 tokens. (So when an employer tries to submit a complaint form an error comes up)

Comment: Please give a [MCVE] including the source code you have so far and an example of where the error is. If you just want to always display zero or more in the report then you can use `GREATEST( token, 0 )` in the query but if you want to generate errors at the appropriate point then you need a lot more information in your question.

Comment: IMO you should change your Business logic. Just let employers make complaint, don't block them. You could either use negative token count, or just keep `token count = 0` (not update token count) instead of `token_count -= 1` when employee with 0 token count got an complaint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about always displaying a number zero-or-greater in the report then you can use `GREATEST( token, 0 )`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tokens ( id, token ) AS
  SELECT 1, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, -9 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       GREATEST( token, 0 ) AS token
FROM   tokens;
```

**Output**:

```
ID | TOKEN
-: | ----:
 1 |    10
 2 |     3
 3 |     0
 4 |     0
 5 |     0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d965bd57a900bcd2f4e0daa49b78a51)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you would in fact be best served with a validation upon submission of a complaint.
When a complaint is made, have a validation run that checks if the employee had tokens, if his tokens are <= 0 then have an error pop up.
The validation can look something like this

```
DECLARE 
  s_tokens NUMBER; 
  b BOOLEAN; 
BEGIN
BEGIN 
  SELECT token_count
    INTO s_tokens
    FROM token_table
   WHERE employee_id = :EMPLOYEE_ID -- taken from the active complaint form

  IF s_tokens <= 0 THEN
    b := FALSE;
  ELSE
    b := TRUE;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN  -- to catch if the employee is not in the table or if anything else messes up
    b := FALSE;
END;
RETURN b;
END;
```

This is a pretty basic validation, you can improve it a lot, but it should work for starters.
Have the validation set up to execute plsql code returning boolean, and then you can change the error text to whatever you want.